# How to get good-looking round shapes with an array and simple deform modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image]
[image]

I tried, but it looks not good even with a lot of vertices. Is there a way to rid of these vertical lines if I created a simple cube and added an array + simple deform modifier?

blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iMoVPBsDuzK6u3vldgC0_c1Qvf8FQtyd/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a round object like this, simply use a 2D profile and a 360°, 0 height screw modifier:

[image]

Comment: good, but if I want to use this for more complicated objects, for example, a wall with a window? Is there a way to get good-looking round shapes with an array and simple deform modifier, not Screw?

Comment: @max they key here is to not produce internal faces. So your starting object may have thickness but no side faces.